# Public transport ticket in Paris

Tags: tickets, public-transport, france, paris

I am traveling to Paris for 3 days (Saturday, Sunday, Monday). I will be staying in La Défense.

I will be mostly  commuting between zones 1 and 3. Does it make sense to buy a Paris Visit (Pass Transport) 3 days (zone 1 to 3) / Adult? It costs 29.40 euros per person.

Is there something that the Netherlands has in Paris? For example, GVB is a company that has bus/metro/tram within the city. If you buy a one-day pass, it will cost you 7 euros and you can take unlimited trips in any of them.

Is there something similar in Paris? Any help from fellow travelers or locals of Paris will be useful.

Comment: Three one-day unlimited-travel passes at Eur7 each is Eur21, which is pretty close to a three-day unlimited-travel-on-all-public-transport pass for Eur29.40 (and [RATP say](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/paris-visite-travel-pass) it's only Eur26.65). What are you asking, exactly?

Comment: It seems, from your question, Paris has a 3-day travel pass and the Netherlands a 1-day pass. Are both not the same thing? (of course, there will be a slight price difference it's Paris after all :-p )

Comment: If you are only travelling between La Défense and Paris, you would only need the standard metro ticket for zone 1-2 _if you travel on the Metro (line 1)_.  If you take other forms of transport (RER, Transilien, ...), or if you are travelling to other locations in zone 3, you would need 1-3.  At [EUR 14.90 for ten tickets](https://www.ratp.fr/en/titres-et-tarifs/t-tickets), this could be less than any of the pass options, depending on how many trips you need to take; unless you're trying to avoid individual tickets.

Comment: I just spent 3 days in Paris and we used our Paris Visit pass not only for the metro, but for free entry to _many_ tourist attractions. If you're going as a tourist I'd highly recommend it - many of the individual attractions are close to €30 each. My only warning is that I seemed to be able to demagnetize the paper ticket they gave me seemingly at will and had to get it replaced several times. There were no questions asked, but it was a hassle to wait in line at the help desk, often with my wife on the other side of the turnstiles waiting for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your options include:

- [Paris visite](https://www.ratp.fr/titres-et-tarifs/forfait-paris-visite), zones 1-3, 3 days: 26.65 EUR. Paper ticket. Includes various discounts and offers.
- [Mobilis](https://www.ratp.fr/titres-et-tarifs/mobilis), zones 1-3: 10 EUR per day, for a total of 30 EUR. Paper ticket.
- [Navigo Jour](https://www.ratp.fr/titres-et-tarifs/forfait-navigo-jour): same rate as Mobilis, but requires a Navigo card. Contactless.
- If you had stayed Friday to Sunday: [Navigo Semaine](https://www.ratp.fr/titres-et-tarifs/forfaits-navigo-mois-et-semaine), all zones, for a week: 22.80 EUR, but works Monday to Sunday only, and requires a Navigo card. Contactless.

So Paris Visite does seem to be your best bet in this situation.

Note that if you want to go for one of the Navigo products, the card itself is free for residents of the region Ile-de-France only in theory. For all others it costs 5 euros.

Answer (score 5):

The Paris Visite is a tourist ticket granting access to certain sights; such products are usually overpriced. However, in this case it's your best bet, as an ordinary day ticket costs €10 for zones 1-3.

So by all means go for it.